# correct way to fetch commits from an upstream to a fork

Tags: git, github

suppose i have a repo name `core`. `core` is the upstream repository. i then have `fork`, which is `core` + commits that will never be pushed to `core`. what is the correct way to keep the `fork` up to date with commits in `core`?

right now, from `fork`, i simply do `git pull core master`. this works, but what happens is it includes previous commits, so when I look at my github log, i see duplicates of a lot of commits.

is this the correct way to do this? is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

> it includes previous commits, so when I look at my github log, i see 
>   duplicates of a lot of commits.

This should not be happening. If you want to maintain your fork, you can use

```
git pull core master
```

or you can 
[rebase the changes](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/11/pull-with-rebase.html)

```
git pull --rebase core master
```

or you can maintain a 
[Topic Branch](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/Topic-Branches).

Comment: or just `git pull --rebase upstream master`

Comment: okay. this was my issue with your previous suggestion. it seemed to be the same as this, but just in a more roundabout way and you didn't explain why. i'm going to try with `--rebase` on the next pull (i've been doing without) and report back.

Comment: okay... so i think it wants me to rebase the entire commit history instead of just the recent history. this is just tedious, but it might have worked if i did it from the beginning. ideas? or should i just go through with it?