# Advice on incorporating outside modifications to an old release using git(1)

Tags: git

I've been given modified source-code files of an old release and would like to incorporate the changes into the current release, which has evolved since the old release. I would like general advice on how to do this in git(1). Note that this is not due to a "pull" request: indeed, I've only been given the files that have been modified and some new files.

Comment: Do you know the commit those modifications were based on?

Comment: I know the commit the modifications are based on.

Comment: Here's an idea: make a branch of this modified code, then rebase your current dev branch upon it. This will probably break a lot of things, but that's the known problem with parallel development. Be brave and resolve conflicts. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Though I see you don't need it, you should make this into an answer so that I can credit you, if appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a branch based on the commit id for which there are modifications

```
$ git checkout <commitid>
$ git branch <name for feature branch>
```

Now apply the modifications in the new branch. Then switch to the branch for the development of the next release and merge the newly created branch.

This does not change any of the existing commits. That should not matter, any release from the past does not contain the modifications and any future release will contain them. The possibility of altering previous releases is a good enough reason to stay away from `rebase` for any code that already has been pushed to another server.

Answer (score 1):

(*posted from comments section as requested*)

Here's an idea: make a branch of this modified code, then rebase your current dev branch upon it. This will probably break a lot of things, but that's the known problem with parallel development. Be brave and resolve conflicts. :)

Comment: I would simply merge and not rebase. A merge does not change existing commits, it simply adds new code for the current release.

Comment: @Sergio The path from the old release to the current is labeled "develop" and has many more commits (215) than your proposed branch of the old release (2) -- so I'd like to keep the "develop" branch. Would creating your branch of the old release, checking out "develop", and then merging your branch be just as difficult/easy?

Comment: @SteveEmmerson: yes, that's what I meant: create a branch with old release, checkout your dev branch and then rebase/merge old release.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you can handle this with a `git pull`, for example

```
git pull upstream master
```

or

```
git pull --rebase upstream master
```

[correct way to fetch commits from an upstream to a fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163030/correct-way-to-fetch-commits-from-an-upstream-to-a-fork)

Comment: The modifications are not in a repository; consequently, a "pull" request is not applicable.